# Where to put HW BP to catch the global variable address corruption?

Tags: c++, gcc, global-variables, breakpoints

Program in C/C++ runs on embedded PowerPC under debugger with HW break points capabilities.
There is global variable 'char Name[256]' known in 2 files and 2 tasks correspondingly. One task reads Name, another fills it with a text, '1234567...', for example.
At some moment, global variable Name gets corrupted. When asked for the variable address gdb shows (and application prints by debug printouts) address equal to 0x31323334.

How to catch this bug with HW breakpoints? I mean at what address to put HWBP. 
When I look into assembler, I see:
    lis 9,Name@ha
    lwz 9,Namel@l(9)

So, how memory corruption can change the code without influencing the application flow - it should crash immediately, no?

Thanks a lot ahead

Answer (score 2):

`0x31323334` is `"1234"` sans null terminator. Further, "Global variable address corruption" does not make much sense "global variables" (whose addresses *do not change*), nor really for an array of size 256 (unless you're using a pointer somewhere and it's the pointer which is being corrupted). So I suspect you might be unfamiliar with GDB.

When using `GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7.1-0ubuntu5~14.04.2) 7.7.1` on x86 (admittedly, not ppc, but basically the same software) with the following test file:

```
// g++ test.cpp -g
#include <iostream>

char Name[256] = "123456789";

int main() {
    Name[0] = 'a';
    std::cout << Name << std::endl;
}
```

I can get the following output from GDB:

```
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 2 at 0x40086a: file test.cpp, line 6.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/keithb/dev/mytest/a.out 

Breakpoint 2, main () at test.cpp:6
6       Name[0] = 'a';
(gdb) whatis Name
type = char [256]
(gdb) print Name
$1 = "123456789", '\000' <repeats 246 times>
(gdb) print &Name
$2 = (char (*)[256]) 0x6010c0 <Name>
```

In any case, if you really do want to set a "hardware breakpoint" ([GDB calls those "watchpoints"](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Watchpoints.html)), then you can do get the address of `Name` prior to corruption. Then just set the watchpoint and wait for your program to write to the address.

```
(gdb) c
Continuing.
a23456789
[Inferior 1 (process 21878) exited normally]
(gdb) delete 2
(gdb) watch *0x6010c0
Hardware watchpoint 3: *0x6010c0
(gdb) r
Starting program: /home/keithb/dev/mytest/a.out 
Hardware watchpoint 3: *0x6010c0

Old value = 875770417
New value = 875770465
main () at test.cpp:7
7       std::cout << Name << std::endl;
(gdb)
```

Comment: I work with gcc/gdb for the last 17 years. And exactly because of this, i asked the question ,because I can't imagine myself the way the address of the global variable can change.
May be I explained this badly, but this is the address of the 'Name' which is changed, not the content.
When I ask gdb to print out the Name address before the problem, it prints 0x51c18. But after the problem occurs, it prints 0x31323334, which is the part of the text copied with memcpy into it. It is not the only text copied, but one of.

Comment: I spoke about watchpoints, because the situation is in multitasking and hard to catch - I already tried BP, printouts, even memory logs.
Everything shows that ADDRESS has changed to the text - the only indication of the problem (except further bus error...:-)

Comment: If truly you think GDB is changing the address of `Name`, then I would try to 1) verify that global `Name` isn't being hidden by a local `Name`, 2) try setting watchpoints on instructions with `Name`'s address hardcoded (such as `lis` and `lws` in your question),

Comment: Sorry, I am really poor in explaining myself.
Definitely, GDB is not changing a thing, but my program does. It only reflects correctly the situation, because the printouts of the address also show it has changed.
Considering the assembler I wrote above, I can't understand how can it happen and this is the question!
If the memory spoiling happens it can't preserver the opcode and registers and spoil only the offsets!

Comment: In my experience, GDB sometimes gets confused about things. It gets progressively worse when 1) debugging an executable with debugging symbols stripped, 2) debugging a heavily-optimized executable, 3) debugging an executable built with a version of GCC which is distinctly different in release year (eg, old GDB with new GCC), and 4) debugging an executable built with a different compiler altogether. Also, your statement about memory corruption preserving opcode and registers while spoiling offsets is not true (read up on undefined behavior).